# Using SDK semaphore in native code

Tags: android-ndk

We have a large c++ codebase that I'm porting onto Android. We had the foresight to abstract various platform-dependent features (threading, file access etc), so the process involves the gradual implementation of Android-appropriate code functions in the NDK

I was getting on reasonably well until I realised that semaphores (used in our core code) don't appear to have an implementation in the NDK.

I was wondering if it were possible under this (and possibly other) circumstances to implement the required functionlity (if it exists) in the SDK, e.g a 'Java' Semaphore and pass it down to the native code via the JNI interface for the native code to operate on it via appropriate callbacks.

Is there a reason why this might be inadviseable for synchronisation purposes?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Have a bad news guys. Semaphore isn't implemented on android version of pthread [google source](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/external/pthreads/+/master/sem_open.c)

As for me flock(2) is an answer. But there is potential problem where you are trying to lock same file from different users.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the worst consequence of using a Java-based implementation that you pass to your native code is that your semaphore operations will be *very* slow since they have to cross the JNI boundary.

Is there any reason why you can't use POSIX semaphores?  See `semaphore.h` from the NDK's headers.

Comment: Thank you kelnos. My mistake- I didn't spot the presence of **semaphore.h** in the includes folder.

Comment: @DaveFussell, did you include semaphore.h from usr/include or usr/include/asm?